# Julia: Trouble setting up parallelization with "using" packages

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I am having big trouble setting up a code for parallelization. When I try to “declare” the packages that I am using in the workers by running the following code:

```
#--------------------------------#
#         Initialization         #
#--------------------------------#

# Packages
#using Distributed

using QuantEcon, Optim, Distributions, DelimitedFiles, ExcelReaders
using ProgressMeter, BenchmarkTools, DataFrames, Combinatorics
using LinearAlgebra, Statistics, Random, StatsBase
using BlackBoxOptim, Distributed

# Number of cores/workers
addprocs(2)

@everywhere begin
    using Pkg; Pkg.activate(".")  # required
    using QuantEcon, Optim, Distributions, DelimitedFiles, ExcelReaders
    using ProgressMeter, BenchmarkTools, DataFrames, Combinatorics
    using LinearAlgebra, Statistics, Random, StatsBase
    using BlackBoxOptim, Distributed
end

# Set Directory

cd("XXX\\julia_codes")
```

I get the following error:

```
<strong>On worker 2:</strong>

<strong>ArgumentError: Package QuantEcon not found in current path:
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("QuantEcon")` to install the QuantEcon package.

require at .\loading.jl:823
top-level scope at XXX\julia_codes\4-Simulations.jl:26
eval at .\boot.jl:328
#116 at C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Julia-1.1.1\share\julia\stdlib\v1.1\Distributed\src\process_messages.jl:276
run_work_thunk at C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Julia-1.1.1\share\julia\stdlib\v1.1\Distributed\src\process_messages.jl:56
run_work_thunk at C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Julia-1.1.1\share\julia\stdlib\v1.1\Distributed\src\process_messages.jl:65
#102 at .\task.jl:259
#remotecall_wait#154(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Distributed.Worker, ::Module, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Julia-1.1.1\share\julia\stdlib\v1.1\Distributed\src\remotecall.jl:421
remotecall_wait(::Function, ::Distributed.Worker, ::Module, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Julia-1.1.1\share\julia\stdlib\v1.1\Distributed\src\remotecall.jl:412
#remotecall_wait#157(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Int64, ::Module, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Julia-1.1.1\share\julia\stdlib\v1.1\Distributed\src\remotecall.jl:433
remotecall_wait(::Function, ::Int64, ::Module, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Julia-1.1.1\share\julia\stdlib\v1.1\Distributed\src\remotecall.jl:433
(::getfield(Distributed, Symbol("##161#163")){Module,Expr})() at .\task.jl:259

...and 7 more exception(s).</strong>

in top-level scope at [stdlib\v1.1\Distributed\src\macros.jl:183](#)

in remotecall_eval at [stdlib\v1.1\Distributed\src\macros.jl:199](#)

in macro expansion at [base\task.jl:245](#)

in sync_end at [base\task.jl:226](#)
```

The usual solutions:

https://discourse.julialang.org/t/packages-and-workers/14072/9

and

https://discourse.julialang.org/t/understanding-everywhere-and-environments/27438

Do not seem to help either.

Comment: With `using Pkg; Pkg.activate(".")`, you are telling the package manager to use the packages specified in the environment of your current directory. Does this environment have everything installed?

Your problem may go away if you omit this line.

Comment: @Korsbo no that does not work either :(

Comment: You are doing this on one machine, I presume, this is not on multiple machines? Then the `Pkg.activate(.)` is certainly incorrect. Without that, code like this does work for me: `addprocs(2); @everywhere using DataFrames`

Comment: AFAICT `@everywhere using Pkg; Pkg.activate(".")` would be needed in the case @Korsbo mentions (i.e. when Project.toml/Manifest.toml  are present in the working directory of the processes and the required packages are not visible in the default environment).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but the suggestions in the comments - removing `Pkg.activate(".")` solved it!

Generally the following works for me:

`using Distributed
 addprocs(12)
 @everywhere begin
 ...all using statements...
 end`

I'm running Julia version 1.0.5